# import code from large js file into react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to use code from this [js file](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/master/polys/geoxml3.js) in my react component. When I do
 `import  * as geoxml3  from '../scripts/geoxml3.js';`
Inside the file I wrapped it with export: 
 `export const geo = ()=> {code}`
It comes up with errors like this:  `objectname is not defined`. How to import the whole contents of the file?

Comment: In order to import someting from file, the file itself must export something.

Comment: @M1K10 tried: export const geo = ()=> { ...file content...} got bunch of  "is not defined " errors.